# function with .filter() returning undefined instead of filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to understand javascript's `Array.filter` method.

Why is the following code returning `undefined`? What am I missing?

```
function driversWithRevenueOver(driver, revenue) {
  driver.filter(function(person) {
    if (person.revenue >= revenue) {
      return person;
    }
  });
}

  driversWithRevenueOver(
    [
      { name: "Sally", revenue: 400 },
      { name: "Annette", revenue: 200 },
      { name: "Jim", revenue: 150 },
      { name: "Sally", revenue: 200 }
    ],
    250
  );
```

It should return:

```
[{ name: 'Sally', revenue: 400 }]
```

Comment: Simply add `return` before `driver.filter`

Answer (score 6):

As per the docs on [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

So in your case main issue is that your function `does not return anything` even though you have called `Array.filter`. So you need to:

```
function driversWithRevenueOver(driver, revenue) {
  return driver.filter(function(person) {  // <-- return here
    return person.revenue >= revenue)
  });
}
```

More info on the function you pass to the `Array.filter` also known as **callback**:

> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return
>   **true** to keep the element, **false** otherwise.

So you need to return a `boolean value` from the function.

A shorter version of this filter could simply be:

```js
let data = [{ name: "Sally", revenue: 400 }, { name: "Annette", revenue: 200 }, { name: "Jim", revenue: 150 }, { name: "Sally", revenue: 200 } ]

let result = data.filter(x => x.revenue > 250)  // <-- function returns boolean

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the result of `filter()` from the function. Also you should return `true` or `false` from `filter()` not a value itself.

```
function driversWithRevenueOver(driver, revenue) {
  return driver.filter(function(person) {
    return person.revenue >= revenue
  });
}
```

With arrow function it will look more clean.

```
const driversWithRevenueOver = (driver, revenue) => 
    driver.filter(person => person.revenue >= revenue);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's returning undefined because your never return to your outer function:

```
function driversWithRevenueOver(driver, revenue) {...}
```

While you do `return` within this function, you are returning to the inner-callback function placed within `.filter(callback)`:

```
driver.filter(function(person) { <---- 
  if (person.revenue >= revenue) {   | returns to callback (not driversWithRevenueOver)
    return person; ------------------|
  }
});
```

Thus, your `driversWithRevenueOver` is implicitly returning `undefined` (as you are not calling returning anything within it). So, you need to return the result of `.filter()`. Moreover, you also need to fix your `return` statement. The filter method will keep items in your original `driver` array if you return `true`, and remove it if you return `false` from within the inner callback. Thus you can simply return the evaluation of `person.revenue >= revenue`:

```
function driversWithRevenueOver(driver, revenue) {
  return driver.filter(function(person) {
    return person.revenue >= revenue;
  });
}
```

```js
function driversWithRevenueOver(driver, revenue) {
  return driver.filter(function(person) {
    return person.revenue >= revenue;
  });
}

const res = driversWithRevenueOver(
  [{
      name: "Sally",
      revenue: 400
    },
    {
      name: "Annette",
      revenue: 200
    },
    {
      name: "Jim",
      revenue: 150
    },
    {
      name: "Sally",
      revenue: 200
    }
  ],
  250
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the filtered array.

```
return driver.filter(...);
```

You can also make your code more concise like so - and note that `filter` just needs a Boolean response.

```js
const driversWithRevenueOver = (driver, revenue) =>  driver.filter(({ revenue: r }) => r >= revenue);

console.log(driversWithRevenueOver(
  [{name:"Sally",revenue:400},{name:"Annette",revenue:200},{name:"Jim",revenue:150},{name:"Sally",revenue:200}],
  250
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just one modification in your code, rest is good.

```
function driversWithRevenueOver(driver, revenue) {
  return driver.filter(function(person) { // you forgot to return the filtered array
    if (person.revenue >= revenue) {
      return person;
    }
  });
}

driversWithRevenueOver(
    [
      { name: "Sally", revenue: 400 },
      { name: "Annette", revenue: 200 },
      { name: "Jim", revenue: 150 },
      { name: "Sally", revenue: 200 }
    ],
    250
);
```